# Best way to implement the notion-like interactive typing interface using html/js or React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

i am trying to prototyping a Notion-like interactive texting interface (something like below). Basically:

- when user type a '/', a context menu could be shown for a couple of selections right next to the typed '/';
- when user choose a selection, a dashboard (or as simple as a popup) will shown right below the input text;

I am curious on what's the best and simplest way to realize this feature? any hints or example codes will be highly appreciated.

[image: menu appeared right next to the latest key stroke]
[image: dashboard appeared right below the latest line]